# pyshorteners not working in executable files

Tags: python

I am trying to use the pyshorteners library in an executable file created from a Python script. The code works perfectly fine when I run it as a Python script, but when I run the executable version, it throws an error:

```
def Shorten_Link(link):
    shortener = pyshorteners.Shortener()
    return shortener.tinyurl.short(link)
```

The error I am getting in the log file is:

```
File "main.py", line 38, in Shorten_Link
  File "pyshorteners\__init__.py", line 32, in __init__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshorteners.shorteners'
```

I am using PyInstaller for the conversion to executable. How can I resolve this issue?
or is there any other easy alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

there are some changes that need to be made in the library. Firstly, you need to navigate to the library directory, which is typically located at:
C:\USER**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyshorteners
**Please replace "USER" with your username.

Once you have navigated to the directory, open the "shorteners" subdirectory and copy all files except for the "init.py" file. Paste these files into the main directory (pyshorteners). Next, open the "**init**.py" file and insert the following code:

```
import logging
import importlib
import pkgutil

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
__version__ = "1.0.1"
__author__ = "Ellison Leão"
__email__ = "ellisonleao@gmail.com"
__license__ = "GPLv3"


class Shortener(object):
    """Base Factory class to create shoreteners instances

    >>> s = Shortener(**kwargs)
    >>> instance = s.shortener_name
    >>> instance.short('http://www.google.com')
    'http://short.url/'

    Available Shorteners can be seen with:

    >>> s = Shortener()
    >>> print(s.available_shorteners)
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        # validate some required fields
        self.kwargs["debug"] = bool(kwargs.pop("debug", False))
        self.kwargs["timeout"] = int(kwargs.pop("timeout", 2))
        self.kwargs["verify"] = bool(kwargs.pop("verify", True))
        module = importlib.import_module("pyshorteners")
        self.available_shorteners = [
            i.name for i in pkgutil.iter_modules(module.__path__)
        ]

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in self.available_shorteners:
            return self.__getattribute__(attr)

        # get instance of shortener class
        short_module = importlib.import_module(
            "{}.{}".format("pyshorteners", attr)
            
        )
        instance = getattr(short_module, "Shortener")(**self.kwargs)

        return instance
```

After that, you will need to import the module that you're using. For example, if you're using the 'tinyurl' attribute of the Shortener class, you'll also need to import it in your code.

I hope I've helped you.